# How do I make an IOS app that has an online mode?

Tags: ios, client

Basically, I'm trying to make a countdown app that reveals information for an event. And when the countdown reaches 0, the information is displayed. I somewhat know that a client app is required for this. So do I need to set a server or something? I just want the basic requirements because I've never made an app that accesses the server/internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you face is that I imagine you don't want people to be able to just change the clock on their device and see the event information. Introducing a server would allow you to check the time independently: the app queries the server, and if the server responds with `MAGIC_UNLOCK_STRING_12345` then the app should reveal its information.

If you are serious about locking down access, you should probably encrypt your app's assets and obfuscate the "unlock now" response string.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the issue I don't want to run into. It's only for a school event so I don't feel encrypting is necessary.

Comment: If it's something small and you don't mind people adjusting their clock to see more information, you don't need a server. If you want *some* security, look for a free time API online that you can call – [http://www.timeapi.org/](http://www.timeapi.org/) used to be good but I think it's struggling with load right now. If you want full-on security, you'd need your own server to respond with the unlock key. If my answer above resolves your question, please mark it as correct so others can benefit too.

Comment: Yeah, I was just waiting for the time to allow me to accept.